# My Inline Image not loading in java mail API with Some other HTML content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is my image path: `<img src=\"cid:image\">`

```
try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(
                    "shaanrisecustomercare@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    "smile.pavi3@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Order Confirmation - Your Order with Shaanrise.com ["
                    + dm.getOrderTrackingId()
                    + "] has been successfully placed!");
            // This HTML mail have to 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
            //
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part  (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();





            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource
              ("D:\\latest codes\\shaanrise\\WebContent\\images\\company-logo.png");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");

            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);
            String orderrsds="<tr><td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getTransactionId()+"</label></td>"+
                    "<td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getProductDescription()+"</label></td><td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getOrderDate()+"</label> </td>"+
                    "<td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getExpectedDelivery()+"</label></td>"+
                    "<td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getQuantity()+"</label></td>"+
                    "<td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getPrice()+"</label></td>"+
                    "<td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>50</label> </td>"+
                    "<td style='border:1px solid grey;'><label>"+dm.getOrderAmount()+"</label></td></tr></table></div>";

            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            sb.append(EmailString.order);
            sb.append(orderrsds);

            String footr=  EmailString.address;
            footr.replace("${to}", dm.getCustomerName());
            footr.replace("${shippingAddress}", dm.getShippingAddress());

            sb.append(footr);


              messageBodyPart.setContent(sb.toString(), "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
              message.setContent(sb.toString(),"text/html");
             // messageBodyPart.setContent(EmailString.logo,"text/html");

             // message.setText(sb.toString(), "text/html");



            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

This is my image path: `<img src=\"cid:image\">`
My images is not loading in java Mail. I'm appending dynamic content in image html page the dynamic content is loading but image is not loading.
I am facing issue as image is only sent as mail.

Comment: <img src=\"cid:image\">

Answer (score 1):

Many mistakes in your code...

You create two MimeBodyParts but assign them to the same variable, the second overwriting the first.  You need two variable, one for the html part and one for the image.

Then after adding these body parts to the multipart and setting the multipart as the content of the message, you overwrite that by setting the content of the message again using the html text.

Create a MimeBodyPart, set the html text content using setText.  Add it to the MimeMultipart.  Create another MimeBodyPart, set the content as the image.  Add it to the MimeMultipart.  Set the MimeMultipart as the content of the message.